# How can I make the user copies a text and gets notified?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In one of my activities I have this `Button`:
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWkbm.png)

I want that once the user clicks on the button two things happen:

1. User copies an email.
2. User gets notified that he copies an email.

So how can I do it?

Thanks in advance ^_^

Answer (score 0):

To copy a text to a clipboard [The Android clipboard framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste#Copying)
And for a simple notification you can use [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts).

So for example:

```
mailBtn.setOnClickListener {
    // Gets a handle to the clipboard service.
    val clipboard = activity?.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    val clip: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("email", "email@email.com")
    // Set the clipboard's primary clip.
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)

    //Notify user.
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Email copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```